# How to interpret CSS documentation notations?

Tags: css, language-lawyer, specifications, css-grid

I'm learning about `CSS Grid` layout and [the article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/grid/) uses the following notation:

```
repeat( [ <positive-integer> ] , [ <line-names>? <track-size> ]+ <line-names>? )
```

I'm unclear on the mean of `[] <> ? +`

Is this notation standard or have a name? If so, where can I learn how to interpret it?

Answer (score 1):

These notations are not unique to the CSS Grid Layout specification.

They are used in the definitions of all CSS properties.

For a complete explanation see the [**CSS Values and Units Module**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) specification.

In particular, see the following section, which explains the meaning of each notation.

> [**2. Value Definition
>   Syntax**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#value-defs)
>
> The syntax described here is used to define the set of valid values
>   for CSS properties. A property value can have one or more components.

For an explanation of this type of grammar read about [**Backus-Naur**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) .

Answer (score 0):

The following code indicates the **template** that you need to use for `repeat()`:

```
repeat( [ <positive-integer> ] , [ <line-names>? <track-size> ]+ <line-names>? )
```

Breaking this down, the components in question mean the following:

- `[]` denotes **required arguments**. Obviously you need to provide something to repeat, and how often it should be repeated. The **first** argument is the number of times to repeat, which obviously needs to be a **positive** integer. The **second** argument is **what** to repeat.
- `<>` denotes that what is contained immediately within is a **placeholder**. The documentation is trying to clarify these components by specifying obvious descriptors like `positive-integer`, but expects you to fill in the values.
- `?` denotes **optional arguments**. Any argument followed directly by a question mark is optional. That is to say, you don't **need** to provide `line-names` for what is being repeated.
- `+` denotes **one or more**. The second `<line-names>` is the **end** point. If provided, the `repeat()` will only go until that line is reached. When not provided, it will continue to the value specified in `<positive-integer>`. Essentially, like the `?`, the `+` is telling you that you **can** provide an end point, but don't have to.

As shown directly below the template in the documentation you linked, a sample bit of code using `repeat()` would be:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 30px 100px);
```

Which is the same as saying:

```
grid-template-columns: 30px 100px 30px 100px 30px 100px 30px 100px;
```

This is because the second parameter (the string `30px 100px`) is repeated as many times as is specified by the first parameter (`4`). No line names or end point is provided in this example, as would be the case in the most common use-case scenario.

More information on CSS Grid's `repeat()` can be found at **[Alligator.io](https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-layout-repeat-notation/)**.

Hope this helps! :)